# Merging multiple kubeconfig files on Windows

Tags: kubernetes

I would like to merge multiple kubeconfig files into one config file.I am using Windows 10 and PS for commnand line. I have 3 config files in `$HOME\.kube\config` directory and I set a *KUBECONFIG* environment variable with `C:\Users\Username\.kube.\config`

I tried below command as below but I received an error says:

> KUBECONFIG=$HOME.kube\config:$HOME.kube\c1.kubeconfig\$HOME.kube\c2.kubeconfig : The module 'KUBECONFIG=$HOME' could not be loaded. For more information, run 'Import-Module KUBECONFIG=$HOME'. At line:1 char:1
>   + KUBECONFIG=$HOME.kube\config:$HOME.kube\c1.kubeconfig\$HOME.k ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (KUBECONFIG=$HOM...2.kubeconfig:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotAutoLoadModule

```
KUBECONFIG=$HOME\.kube\config:$HOME\.kube\c1.kubeconfig\$HOME\.kube\c2.kubeconfig kubectl config view --merge --flatten $HOME\.kube\merged_kubeconfig
```

My Folder structure as below.

```
.kube
  -c1.kubeconfig
  -c2.kubeconfig
  -config
```

Answer (score 5):

Resolved issue with merging kubeconfig files using below command for Windows

```
$Env:KUBECONFIG=("$HOME\.kube\config;$HOME\.kube\c1.kubeconfig;$HOME\.kube\c2.kubeconfig"); kubectl config view --merge --flatten | Out-File "C:\Users\SU\tmp\config"
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to update the command to use semicolon as a delimiter for Windows

like Note the usage of ;

```
$Env:KUBECONFIG=("$HOME\.kube\config;$HOME\.kube\c1.kubeconfig")
```

Test by echo to check what you get updated

```
echo $Env:KUBECONFIG
C:\Users\DT\.kube\config;C:\Users\DT\.kube\c1.kubeconfig
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do first command and it worked, but I wanted to put the output file imediatelly into `$HOME\.kube\` without any middle step. (Creating new file somewhere else.) I couldn't have done it with Out-File command. The out config file always contained only content from the second file. So here is my solution:

```
$Env:KUBECONFIG=("$HOME\.kube\config;$HOME\Downloads\config"); kubectl config view --merge --flatten | Set-Content $HOME\.kube\config
```

For the second config I am using "Downloads" folder, because it is the place where I usually download files, but you can change it to whatever you want.

And the main difference between mine solution and the first answer is Set-Content command.